bunx command fails when running inside a Docker container
I'm trying to download a file from a Cloudflare R2 bucket using Wrangler on a Docker container and bunx but I keep getting errors that I believe are unrelated to Wrangler and might be related to how Docker works
Here is the command:
docker run --rm -ti --env CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN=xxx -v $(pwd)/storage:/home/bun/app/ oven/bun:debian bunx wrangler r2 object get bucket/backup/server-20241019192950.sql.gz -J eu
running wrangler r2 object get bucket/backup/server-20241019192950.sql.gz -J eu outside Docker, works just fine but when I run inside Docker, this is what I get
 ⛅️ wrangler 3.81.0
-------------------

Downloading "backup/server-20241019192950.sql.gz" from "sumiu-files (eu)".
13028 |       );
13029 |     }
13030 |     __name(finalizeAndReportTiming, "finalizeAndReportTiming");
13031 |     function markResourceTiming(timingInfo, originalURL, initiatorType, globalThis2, cacheState) {
13032 |       if (nodeMajor > 18 || nodeMajor === 18 && nodeMinor >= 2) {
13033 |         performance.markResourceTiming(timingInfo, originalURL.href, initiatorType, globalThis2, cacheState);
                            ^
TypeError: performance.markResourceTiming is not a function. (In 'performance.markResourceTiming(timingInfo, originalURL.href, initiatorType, globalThis2, cacheState)', 'performance.markResourceTiming' is undefined)
      at markResourceTiming (/tmp/bunx-0-wrangler@latest/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:13033:21)
      at finalizeAndReportTiming (/tmp/bunx-0-wrangler@latest/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:13022:7)
      at handleFetchDone (/tmp/bunx-0-wrangler@latest/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:12965:68)
      at /tmp/bunx-0-wrangler@latest/node_modules/wrangler/wrangler-dist/cli.js:13309:44

I tried passing a different user to the Docker run, assuming the issue could be related to user and root permissions, but it didn't do anything.
